# Web api C# POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, postman

I'm working on ASP net, and i have problem with post api.
 I'm testing my api with postman, and have the Following message :

[image]

Here is my code of POST verb :

```
 // POST: api/Boooks
        [Route("~/api/PostCreate")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Books books)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest("Invalid data.");


            // > (Variable)  Objet de connection PostGreSql qui va recevoir la connextion PostGre <
                Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection Psconnection;

            // > (Variable) Objet de connexion pour appel de la méthode 
            Sql_Connect_Data_Base ObjCnxDB = new Sql_Connect_Data_Base();

            // > On execute la connextion à la base et on recupert un objet connection <
            //   > On récupère l'objet de connexion dans "Psconnection" qui est retrourné par "ObjCnxDB.InitConnexionPostGres()" <
            Psconnection = ObjCnxDB.InitConnexionPostGres();


            // > Important : on doit respecter la casse dans les noms de colonnes <
            String ChnSqlInsert;
            // > Si le paramètre recçu est différent de nul <
            if (books != null)
                {
                ChnSqlInsert = books.ID;
                    }
            else 
            // > Object null ==> Eror message 
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid data.");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ID_AUTO` property in your `Books` class from int to string since your json shows that to be a string.

Or you can change your value in postman to an int from string. Remove the quotes around 0 for ID_AUTO

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.  But I can't change ID_AUTO property because it's calculating from database in the sql insert instruction.

Comment: I remove the quotes around 0 for ID_AUTO, and Postman sends me the same error. So, i really Don't understand where is the problem...